# VB.NET + LINQ: Save in a single class attribute the result of querying two columns from different tables

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two tables: Estructura (with two fields I want: descripcion_morologica and interpretacion) and estrato (with two fields I want: descripcion_larga and interpretacion_explic). On the other side I hace a class in VS with the attributes descripcion and interpretacion. Both tables have a common field called id_excavacion, which I pass to the method as a parameter.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make a query which saves in the "descripcion" attribute the results of t1.descripcion_morfologica and t2.descripcion_larga and also saves in "interpretacion" the results of t1.interpretacion and t2.interpretacion_explic.

So far, I've tried like this:

```
'GET: api/Excavacions/ListadoUE/5
    <Route("api/Excavacions/ListadoUE/{idExcavacion}")>
    Function GetListadoUEs(ByVal idExcavacion As Integer) As IQueryable(Of ListadoUEDto)
        Dim listado =
            From estru In db.Estructura
            Join estra In db.Estrato On estra.id_excavacion Equals estru.id_excavacion
            Where estru.id_excavacion = idExcavacion
            Select New ListadoUEDto With {
               .Descripcion = estru.descripcion_morfologica And estra.descripcion_larga,
                .Interpretacion = estru.interpretacion And estra.interpretacion_explic
            }
    End Function
```

But I only get null, despite the id I pass actually exists.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost certainly not be using `And` there. That is a Boolean operator, for combining `True` and `False` values. As is always the case, if you want to concatenate `Strings` then you use `&`, which is the string concatenation operator.

You should have `Option Strict On` and then the compiler would have warned you that you were doing something that doesn't make sense. You should turn it `On` in the project properties and also in the VS options, so it is `On` by default for future projects. That will force you to put more thought into what data types you use and, therefore, make you write better code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jmcilhinney for taking the time to help me. However I couldn't get what I wanted with your solution. After a lot of reading, what I needed was a Union

Comment: @Calfa, I can see how your description could mean that but there's no way that I would have inferred that it did. For future reference, it is a good idea to provide example inputs and outputs. That would have made it abundantly clear that you were talking about combining vertically rather than horizontally.

Comment: @Calfa, I'll leave this answer for a brief period and then delete it, given that it doesn't answer the question you were asking. You should post and accept your own answer, so that it might help others in the future. Always provide your own answer if you answer your own question, assuming that there's no restriction based on reputation points.

Comment: Thanks, @jmcilhinney. The reason I didn't explain my problem better is just because I couldn't explain to myself what I was trying to do, and of course, I didn't even know the concept of "union". However, now that I read again I have to totally agree with you. As soon as I get home today, I will correct my OP and I will also post the answer. Thanks for your recommendations and for your time. Cheers!